# JPA: Store a list of integers in a single field

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to store a list of integers in a single field of the respective entity table with standard JPA 2?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_myentities")
public class MyEntity {

@ElementaryCollection
@Column(name="vals") // in table tbl_myentities
private List<Integer> vals;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not possible to store multiple values in a single field. Whats the reason behind storing them in a single field?

A way could be to use a field of type String and add all integers there in a comma separated list and join/explode in getters and setters:

```
private String vals;

public setVals(int vals[])
{
     // this.vals = Iterate vals[] and create a comma separated string
}

public int[] getVals()
{
    // vals.split(",") to get a list of Strings, then typecast/parse them to ints before returning
}
```

Using the `@ElementCollection` annotation and `@CollectionTable` to control the mappings requires a separate table to store the values in.

```
@ElementCollection
private Collection<Integer> integers;
```

Read more about element collections on on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Similar question here [Does JPA @ElementCollection annotation always produce an one-to-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592242/does-jpa-elementcollection-annotation-always-produce-an-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: It says, "The ElementCollection values are always stored in a separate table."

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a converter and use it with the annotation @Converter.

This converter must implement AttributeConverter which is a generic interface with two methods convertToDatabaseColumn and convertToEntityAttribute.

It is pretty easy to work with, you can check here: [jpa independent custom type mapping / javax.persistence.x alternative to org.hibernate.annotations.Type and org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973361/jpa-independent-custom-type-mapping-javax-persistence-x-alternative-to-org-hib/24194996#24194996)

Answer (score 3):

You can store all the vals in a String field, separated with a comma, and change associated getter and setter like that :

```
public List<Integer> getVals() {
    List<Integer> lstVals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int val = 0;

    for(String field : this.vals.split(",")) {
        try {
            val = Integer.parseInt(field);
        }
        // If the String contains other thing that digits and commas
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        lstVals.add(val);
    }

    return lstVals;
}

public void setVals(List<Integer> vals) {
    String newVals = "";
    for(int i : vals) {
        newVals.concat(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    this.vals = newVals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. Because you can not have a column in a database table that allows you to store list of integers.

What you can do is use a string type field instead of list of integers -

```
@Column(name="vals") // in table tbl_myentities
private String vals;
```

And do the conversion to string from list of integers and back manually before you save your entity and after you have read your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a @Lob could suit you ? (despite what it imply)

```
@Lob
ArrayList<String> vals;
```

(note that your collection must be explicitly an ArrayList)

Comment: @Wingie Are your getter/setter also explicitly for ArrayList ?

Comment: Getting the following error with this:

```class=java.lang.ClassCastException, error=java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob```

Don't think this solution works.