# jpa independent custom type mapping / javax.persistence.x alternative to org.hibernate.annotations.Type and org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table `GameCycle` in a db that holds a column `date` of type `number`. The values in this column are 8-digit numbers representing an inverse date like '`20130301`'. Mapped onto this table i have a class `GameCycle` that holds a protected field iDate of type `java.util.Date`. That field is annotated '`@Type(type = "inverseDate")`', using a custom type mapping. The class `Gamecycle` is annotated with '`@TypeDef(name = "inverseDate", typeClass = InverseDateType.class)`'

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "inverseDate", typeClass = InverseDateType.class)
@Table(name = "GAMECYCLE")
public class GameCycle implements Comparable<GameCycle>, Serializable
{
    @Type(type = "inverseDate")
    @Column(name = "GC_DATE", nullable = false)
    protected Date iDate = null;
    ...
```

Obviously, the imports bind me to using hibernate as a jpa implementation so my question is:

Is there a way to get rid of the hibernate annotations and do the same custom type mapping using a pure `javax.persistence` solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Current version of JPA specification doesn't support custom type mappings. It's one of the most wanted features for future JPA 2.1.

If you really want to get rid of Hibernate-specific annoations, the only thing you can do is to map your field as `String` and perform necessary conversion manually (in getters/setters).

But in practice almost every large JPA-based application uses some implementation-specific features of persistence provider, therefore I don't think that avoiding dependency on Hibernate in this case really matters.

Comment: Too bad, i had suspected that the only solution besides being bound to an implementation would be some conversion in the getters/setters. Thank you for the quick answer though.

Answer (score 47):

**Custom Type Mapping** has been finally added in **JPA 2.1** ([JSR-388](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338), part of Java EE 7).
The Hibernate's [@Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Type.html) annotation is no longer needed, and can be replaced by **Type Conversion** in JPA 2.1.

JPA 2.1 has added :

- annotation [@Convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html)
- annotation [@Converts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converts.html)
- annotation [@Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html)
- interface [AttributeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html)

The most basic example : (*Example 1:  Convert a basic attribute*) - [from source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html)

```
@Converter
public class BooleanToIntegerConverter 
    implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Integer> 
{  ... }
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee
{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = BooleanToIntegerConverter.class)
    private boolean fullTime;

}
```

Other links :

- [Type Conversion in JPA 2.1](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/type_conversion_in_jpa_2)
- [JPA 2.1 - How to implement a Type Converter](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html)
- [Mapping Enums Done Right With @Convert in JPA 2.1](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mapping-enums-done-right)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now that JPA 2.1 has arrived.