# Automatically convert a parameter with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In our entity beans we use a custom ID format which includes a checksum to verify that the ID is actually valid. Ids look like `ID827391738979`. To make sure that all code uses correct IDs only we created a code wrapper around an ID String:

```
class ID {
    public ID(String id) {
       // parse and verify ID
    }

    public String toString() {
       return id;
    }
}
```

All code just uses this `ID` object. However in our entity we have defined the ID as a `String`:

```
class SomeEntity {
    @Column
    private String itsID;
}
```

Now we want to use Spring-Data-JPA to query some object by it's id. So we do:

```
public SomeEntity findByItsID(ID itsId);
```

Problem is, that now Spring Data JPA tries to assign the ID-typed parameter to the query, while the query of course expects a `String`.

Is it possible to have Spring Data JPA convert the parameter to the expected type (e.g. by registering a Spring converter) before it is inserted into the query? Or, do we have to let the method take a String like this:

```
public SomeEntity findByItsId(String itsId);
```

I would rather avoid this, so all code can use the `ID` class instead of resorting to Strings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use a [custom type in your entity with JPA 2.1 `@Convert`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194996/1064325), so JPA makes the conversion for you (I've tested it with Spring Data JPA also, and it worked transparently!), see:

Entity:

```
@Entity
class SomeEntity {

    @Column(name = "my_id_column_name")
    @Convert(converter = MyIDConverter.class)
    private ID itsID;
}
```

Converter:

```
public class MyIDConverter implements AttributeConverter<ID, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ItStaticDataKey javaKey) {
        // your implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public ItStaticDataKey convertToEntityAttribute(final String databaseKey) {
        // your implementation here
    }

}
```

Notes:

1. Make sure you're using a JPA-2.1-compatible Spring Data JPA version. (I'm sure that Spring Data JPA 1.7.0 (and above) are (or at least should) be compatible).
2. Unfortunately, [it won't work if that field should also be annotated with `@Id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391943/1064325).
3. If you use EclipseLink, you have to define converter in persistence.xml, or it doesn't pick it up. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412454.
4. With JPA on Spring, package containing converters have to appear in property `packageToScan` on `EntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Comment: Thanks for number 2 been siting with it for two hours

Comment: will a converter of type AttributeConverter<String, String> work? Its doesnt seem to be getting picked up by JPA

Comment: @Vladimir : From `AttributeConverter<X,Y>`s JavaDoc:
 " A class that implements this interface can be used to convert entity attribute state into database column representation and back again. Note that the X and Y types may be the same Java type."

Comment: Also you can't have both `@Convert` and `@Enumerated` on the field at the same time (I made this mistake and the converter was not taken into account).

Comment: @falsarella How to deal with multiple datasource configuration ? I am not able to get the property value from properties file when I use multiple datasource configuration.

Comment: Sorry @Krish I've been focused on frontend for some time. But it looks like your issue is more related to the configuration itself than the converter.

Comment: If you add `@Converter(autoApply = true)`  to the converter-class, you can omit the `@Convert...` annotation and the converter is used automatically in all places where it fits.