# JPA/Hibernate: AttributeConverter does not convert a class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

There is a class `Order` with `inks` field which is a collection of 4 possible `Ink` constants: `Ink.YELLOW, Ink.MAGENTA, Ink.CYAN, Ink.BLACK`. `Inks` are converted into single `Integer` as a bit mask using each `Ink`'s position. For example `{ Ink.MAGENTA, Ink.CYAN } => 0110 => 6`.

For some reason `AttributeConverter` receives empty `Inks` when saving entity to database and always produces `0` in database column. When it is run directly everything works just fine.

I see the `AttributeConverter` is being run twice. `Inks` argument is empty only the second time. I believe something is wrong with mapping.

**Order**

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    public int id;   

    @Convert(converter = InksConverter.class)
    public Inks inks = new Inks();

    //...
}
```

**Inks**

```
public class Inks {
    private TreeSet<Ink> set = new TreeSet<>();

    public Inks(Ink... inks) {
        set.add(inks);
    }

    public void add(Ink... inks) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inks.length; i++) set.add(inks[i]);
    }

    public int toInteger() {
        Integer i = 0;
        for (Ink ink : set) i |= (1 << ink.id);
        return i;
    }

    public Inks fromInteger(int i) {   
        Inks inks = new Inks();
        Ink.set.forEach(ink -> {
            if ((i & (1 << ink.id)) == 1) inks.add(ink);
        });
        return inks;
    }

    //...
}
```

**InksConverter**

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class InksConverter implements AttributeConverter<Inks, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Inks inks) {
        return inks.toInteger();
    }

    @Override
    public Inks convertToEntityAttribute(Integer i) {           
        return Inks.fromInteger(i);
    }
}
```

**Saving order into database**

```
Session session = configuration.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
Order order = new Order();
order.inks.add(Ink.BLACK, Ink.CYAN);
session.save(order);
session.close();
```

Comment: If I make `convertToDatabaseColumn` return a fixed number this number is successfully stored into column.

Comment: What do you mean "When it runs directly"?

Comment: Your code wont work, the method 'add' of 'inks' of 'order' does not exists

Comment: `new InksConverter().convertToDatabaseColumn(new Inks(Ink.YELLOW))` produces `1`

Comment: It exists of course. See corrected listing.

Comment: I just take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337798/hibernate-fails-to-load-jpa-2-1-converter-when-loaded-with-spring-boot-and-sprin/28391943 and see this man have @Converter(autoApply = true) for his class, did you missed it?

Comment: No, that's not an issue here. I have it in my code and I see the converter is being run