# @Convert in Hibernate not working with spring 4,java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

Tags: java, hibernate, pom.xml, jpa-2.1

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.aratan.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>reporting-module</artifactId>
<version>A1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>reporting-module</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/reporting-module</path>
                <!--<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.0</servlet.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.57</tomcat.version>
    <!--<tomcat.version>8.0.30</tomcat.version>-->

    <!-- Spring -->
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-E from Project-B -->
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>4.0.0-CR1</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->



    <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>RELEASE</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>





    <!-- Other Web dependencies -->

    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>2.5</version>-->
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.20100224</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Websocket & Tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Logging with SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>






    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>2.7</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->





    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JWT -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Exec cmd -->
    <!-- dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency -->

    <!-- Google GSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Templating -->
    <!-- dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.21</version>
    </dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.mqtt-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>mqtt-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!---->
    <!-- File upload (MultiPartResolver) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- SFTP Connection via JSch -->
    <!-- dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.51</version>
    </dependency -->



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>





</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.apache.tomcat</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

```
    package com.aratan.myapp.imports.convertor;

    import com.aratan.myapp.imports.constant.ImportType;

    import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
    import javax.persistence.Converter;

    /**
     * Created by ashishratan on 17/9/16.
     */

    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public class ImportTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ImportType, Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(ImportType x) {
            return x.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public ImportType convertToEntityAttribute(Integer y) {
            return ImportType.getById(y);
        }
    }







 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.aratan.myapp.dao.CustomerDao com.aratan.myapp.service.LoginServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/aratan/myapp/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    ......
    .....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.aratan.myapp.dao.CustomerDao com.aratan.myapp.service.LoginServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/aratan/myapp/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/aratan/myapp/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/aratan/myapp/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder$ConverterRegistrationDelegate.registerConverter(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:389)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:311)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 86 more
```

This is my Entity class that is using @Convert

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "imports")
public class Import {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long tenantId;
    @Column
//    @Type(type = "com.aratan.myapp.imports.convertor.ImportType")
    @Convert(converter = ImportTypeConverter.class)
    private ImportType type;
// all setter getter
}
```

here is my Hibernate config class.

```
package com.aratan.myapp.config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by ashishratan on 12/8/16.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {


//    @Autowired
//    private Environment env;

    //${jdbc.driverClassName}
    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;


    @Bean()
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return htm;
    }


    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean asfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        asfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        asfb.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        asfb.setPackagesToScan("com.aratan.myapp");
        return asfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);

        return properties;
    }

}
```

Comment: Move your hibernate dependency above spring or use managed dependencies to force hibernate version

Comment: The stack trace indicates a problem with your hibernate config: `Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/aratan/myapp/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V`. Would help, if you a) tell us where exactly you get stuck, and b) post the hibernate config

Comment: @SamiKorhonen how to use managed dependencies ??

Comment: @deepblue - Problem comes when i add `@Covert` in my converter clas `ImportTypeConverter`

Comment: @deepblue - `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;)V`

Comment: Add: <dependencyManagement><dependencies>    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency></dependencies></dependencyManagement> to your pom.xml. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: In the libs of the project, what version is the hibernate-commons-annotations lib?

Comment: @deepblue- it's `2.1` in dependency tree, as well i have exclude as `hibernate-core` was using `2.0`. see upadate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing **Hibernate Version**, The issue was in **4.2.1.Final**, changed with **4.3.13.Final** and it works.

`Root Cause:`

> Spring was Using Hibernate4 and LocalSessionFactoryBean class 
>       was tryinh to register the converter by Something like org.hibernate.cfg.Congiguartion.addConverter(....)
>        and this method was not availabale in hibernate 4.2.1

Changed::

```
<!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
<hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

has your private CustomerDao filed public getter and setter method?

Comment: Issue is not in Customer Dao. i am not posing here my all project. Inspite the calss that is causion the issue.