# Any way to preprocess @Column into a DB wrapping function for loading the value?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

It would be great if I could do something like (it's just an example):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   @Id 
   public String id;

   @Column(wrapInto = "UUID_GENERATE_V3(@Id)")
   public String uuid;
}
```

So JPA would magically wrap this into the field when translating into the underlying query. It is really useful for substrings, custom extensions... so I feel like it must exist a mechanism

Comment: [How to implement a JPA Attribute Converter](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/), [Automatically convert a parameter with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399046/5380322)

Comment: ``@Column(columnDefinition="your value")``

Comment: Is columnDefinition useful for reading or just for writing? I mean is columnDefinition="VARCHAR DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V3(id)" going to work when loading the entity as a virtual field?

Comment: @Cepr0 Converters are meant to be used for doing the conversion in Java