# How to use Spring Data / JPA to insert into a Postgres Array type column?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Say I have a postgres table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);
```

Would I even be able to use Spring Data to insert into the columns `pay_by_quarter` or `schedule` ? If possible, how would this look as a Repository and Entity ? I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples addressing this, possibly because of how it overlaps with the more common use-case, inserting into multiple tables as one-to-many relations. Speaking of which, I fully intend to use the Postgresql `array` datatype and no relational tables.

Comment: Yes, you could achieve this with Spring Data. However, I suggest this is a very bad practice, violating the 1NF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). If possible, consider a model revision..

Comment: @crm86 I prefer to not have FNF for the particular data I am saving (mass streams of tweets from twitter). I want to store the one-to-many relations in a single table (to avoid so many joins for such poorly valued data). I also want to avoid NoSQL document databases as they are unruly to maintain for me. I suppose another alternative to `array` data type would be `JSONB` and store everything as a document in postgresql. But I think working with columns (and a few array datatypes) is better than working with JSON (in Postgresql).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to create your own type and implement the `UserType interface`. Based in next [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023528/4751165) I've written a Generic `UserType` to use in all arrays and it works but you must use **non primitive data types** (Integer, Long, String,...). Otherwise see the above update with `Boolean` type.

```
public class GenericArrayUserType<T extends Serializable> implements UserType {

    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };
    private  Class<T> typeParameterClass;

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (T) this.deepCopy(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {

        if (x == null) {
            return y == null;
        }
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        if (resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null) {
            return new Integer[0];
        }

        Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T javaArray = (T) array.getArray();
        return javaArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
        if (value == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
        } else {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T castObject = (T) value;
            Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", (Object[]) castObject);
            statement.setArray(index, array);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> returnedClass() {
        return typeParameterClass;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
    }


}
```

Then the array properties would be same type of data base with same dimension:

- `integer[]` -> `Integer[]`
- `text[][]`-> `String[][]`

And in this special cases put the `GenericType` class above the properties

```
@Type(type = "packageofclass.GenericArrayUserType")
```

Then your entity would be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sal_emp")
public class SalEmp {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Column(name="pay_by_quarter")
    @Type(type = "packageofclass.GenericArrayUserType")
    private Integer[] payByQuarter;

    @Column(name="schedule")
    @Type(type = "packageofclass.GenericArrayUserType")
    private String[][] schedule;

    //Getters, Setters, ToString, equals, and so on

}
```

If you don't want to use this Generic `UserType` the `Integer[]` type and write the `String[][]` type. You need to write your own types, in your case there would be as next:

- integer[]

  ```
  public class IntArrayUserType implements UserType {

  protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

  @Override
  public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return this.deepCopy(cached);
  }

  @Override
  public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return value;
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return (Integer[]) this.deepCopy(value);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {

      if (x == null) {
          return y == null;
      }
      return x.equals(y);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
      return x.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
          throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
          return null;
      }
      if (resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null) {
          return new Integer[0];
      }

      Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
      Integer[] javaArray = (Integer[]) array.getArray();
      return javaArray;
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
          throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
      if (value == null) {
          statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
      } else {
          Integer[] castObject = (Integer[]) value;
          Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", castObject);
          statement.setArray(index, array);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return original;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Integer[]> returnedClass() {
      return Integer[].class;
  }

  @Override
  public int[] sqlTypes() {
      return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
  }
  }
  ```
- text[][]

  ```
  public class StringMultidimensionalArrayType implements UserType {

  protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

  @Override
  public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return this.deepCopy(cached);
  }

  @Override
  public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return value;
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return (String[][]) this.deepCopy(value);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {

      if (x == null) {
          return y == null;
      }
      return x.equals(y);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
      return x.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
          throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
          return null;
      }
      if (resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null) {
          return new String[0][];
      }

      Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
      String[][] javaArray = (String[][]) array.getArray();
      return javaArray;
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
          throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
      if (value == null) {
          statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
      } else {
          String[][] castObject = (String[][]) value;
          Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", castObject);
          statement.setArray(index, array);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return original;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<String[][]> returnedClass() {
      return String[][].class;
  }

  @Override
  public int[] sqlTypes() {
      return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
  }

  }
  ```

In this case your properties has different types:

```
@Column(name="pay_by_quarter")
@Type(type = "packageofclass.IntArrayUserType")
private Integer[] payByQuarter;

@Column(name="schedule")
@Type(type = "packageofclass.StringMultidimensionalArrayType")
private String[][] schedule;
```

#### **Update Hibernate UserType**

With Boolean or boolean seems It doesn't works with `GenericArrayUserType`, so the solutions could be create in your `CREATE DDL` declare `boolean`of type `bytea`:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][],
    wow_boolean     bytea
    );
```

And your property without any type:

`private boolean[][][] wowBoolean;`

It parses very good without any `Type`or `Converter`. Output: `wowBoolean=[[[true, false], [true, false]], [[true, true], [true, true]]])`

**Update With `@Converter` of `JPA 2.1`**

I've tried an option with `@Converter`of JPA 2.1 with `EclipseLink`and `Hibernate`. I've just tried `integer[]` (not `text[][]`) `Converter`like this (*I've changed the property to a `List<Integer>` but it doesn't matter):

```
@Converter
public class ConverterListInteger implements AttributeConverter<List<Integer>, Array>{

    @Override
    public Array convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Integer> attribute) {
        DataSource source = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(DataSource.class);

        try {
            Connection conn = source.getConnection();
            Array array = conn.createArrayOf("integer", attribute.toArray());
            return  array;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> convertToEntityAttribute(Array dbData) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            for(Object object : (Object[]) dbData.getArray()){
                list.add((Integer) object);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;

    }

}
```

Then, add the converter to the property in the Entity:

```
@Convert(converter=ConverterListInteger.class)
private List<Integer> pay_by_quarter;
```

So the solution based on the `JPA specification` doesn't works. Why? Hibernate does not support database arrays (`java.sql.Array`)....

Then I've tried with EclipseLink (see how to configure [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/eclipselink)) and it works, but not always ...It seems there's a bug, It works the first time well but then next times it's not possible to update or query this row. Then just I've success add new rows but It's not possible to update or query after....

### **Conclusion**

At the moment, It seems there is not supported by `JPA` vendors properly... Only the solution with `Hibernate` `UserType` works well but it's just for `Hibernate`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there any way to do this without depending on Hibernate?? For example, would it be possible to not use `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` ?? Or is depending on Hibernate the only solution for this use-case?

Comment: This solution depends on `hibernate` I know, but it think is easier. If you want don't depend on 'Hibernate' you could use `@Converter` of Jpa 2.1. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24194996/4751165

Comment: In the example dealing with JPA 2.1 you use the `Array` type, that is the `java.sql.Array` right?

Comment: You have never initialized typeParameterClass in your first code block. Don't you get a null pointer exception?

Comment: I get the following error using GenericArrayUserType: "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003"

Comment: @chomp: in `@Column` add something like `columnDefinition = "text[]"`.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I ended up using this library: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types

Comment: Unfortunately among others the equals method in IntArrayUserType does not work. If x is an int[] and y is an Integer[] with the same numbers, x.equals(y) will be false.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Approach will be**

try to convert string[] to string  and then in Entity class make

`@Column(name = "nice_work" columnDefinition="text")`

function for converting string[] to string and vice-versa

```
private static String stringArrayTOString(String[] input) {
        StringBuffer sb =new StringBuffer("");
        int i=0;
        for(String value:input) {
            
            if(i!=0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(value);
            i++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    private static String[] stringToStringArray(String input) {
        String[] output = input.split(",");
        return output;
    }
```