# How to properly map MonetaryAmount using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

When I am trying to map my custom Expenditure object to relational model in MySQL, I got error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javax.money.MonetaryAmount, at table: Expenditure, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(monetaryAmount)]
```

My Expenditure class:

```
@Entity
public class Expenditure implements Comparable<Expenditure> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String description;

    private MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount;

    private LocalDate date;

    private ExpenditureType type;

    @OneToOne
    private User client;
...
}
```

How can I perform mapping in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jpa'2 `@Convert` annotation:

```
@Convert(converter = MonetaryAmountConverter.class)
private MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount;
```

And then implement it like this:

```
@Converter
public class MonetaryAmountConverter implements AttributeConverter<MonetaryAmount, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToDatabaseColumn(MonetaryAmount attribute) {...}

    @Override
    public MonetaryAmount convertToEntityAttribute(BigDecimal dbData) {...}
}
```

Comment: Where is the currency ?

Comment: Map to String instead of BigDecimal. Otherwise you'll loose the currency.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store the currency as well, then you should use Vlad Mihalceas https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils:

```
@CompositeType(MonetaryAmountType.class)
private MonetaryAmount amount;
```

the database should hold both an amount and a currency:

```
<column name="amount" type="decimal(19,4)"/>
<column name="currency" type="char(3)"/>
```

If you need different names (e.g. when you have several amounts in your table), then go for @AttributeOverride:

```
@AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "amount_in_question"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "currency", column = @Column(name = "amount_in_question_currency"))
@CompositeType(MonetaryAmountType.class)
private MonetaryAmount amountInQuestion;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot map MonetaryAmount directly.

You can try mapping it to BigDecimal, then in your code perform a conversion, or you can try implementing a Hibernate custom type (try searching for `@Type`, or using JPA conversion (if JPA is 2.1 or above). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194996/4146565) has some nice links on the subject.