# How do I store multiple column values in single String?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc, scriptlet

I want multiple column data inn single string variable ,I tried But I only get Single column Data,What should I do.here Is my coding Image[And my query is"select PRODUCT_ID_LIST from ORDERS where USER_ID=?" and code iamge is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD04Z.png)

[my table image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGrS.jpg)

I want is that the whole column values in string and then string will be split by comma.
I have split code.

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread but if I understood correctly, I hope we have a possible situation and at the same time solution too at this existing thread. - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065620/jpa-store-a-list-of-integers-in-a-single-field)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I fully understand what you need, but look up the SQL CONCAT(...) function. It will depend on your database though if it is supported.

Comment: When execute my code see 1 image, I only get single column in that variable.and I want I all columns data into that variable.

Comment: Soooooo use '||' then?
i.e. SELECT ID, Namee || " " || Family AS NameS
FROM Students

Comment: Didn't get it.please write full query,I posted above. Thanks

Comment: I solved it.using string builder class.thanks for helping guys.