# How to store 60 integers in a class to be written/read from a database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm setting up an application to keep track of scores of an archery shoot. Each shoot consists of 60 arrows ranging from 0-10. What would be the best way of setting up the class to store every arrows score, to then be written into an SQLite database?

I could set up a variable for every single arrow but this seems inefficient. What is the better way of doing this?

```
public class Portsmouth {

    private int id;
    Date date;
    private int arrow1;
    private int arrow2;
    private int arrow3;
    ...
    private int arrow60;

}
```

Comment: Err. Just so that I get it: you are writing android code, you intend to work with a database, but you haven't heard of **arrays** in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use an integer array like this:

```
import java.lang.System; //imported by default

public class Portsmouth {

    private int id;
    Date date;
    private int[] arrow; 

    public Portsmouth(int id, Date data, int[] arr){
      this.id = id;
      this.date = date;
      arrow = new int[60];

      System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arrow, 0, 60);

      /**for(int i=0;i<60;i++){
         arrow[i] = arr[i];
      }**/
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.arraycopy(...)` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

Use an `int[]` array or `List<Integer>` collection instead of defining the fields one by one.

The SQL that you run to instert rows into the database depends on your schema e.g. table being de-normalized with 60 columns vs 60 rows, one for each arrow. Usually one separates the domain model from the schema with a pattern like [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an Arrow class which will have your score for that arrow 1-10. Then an ILIST of arrow in another class called Shoot. Then I will imagine you have another tournament and/or  shooter class for which you include properties in the Shoot class. Give it a try if you like it and I can expand.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on pushing/pulling all of the information to a database, one way to move this data would be to use [Java Persistence API (JPA).](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa) This way you can push or pull the data easily. One limitation of JPA is that **each column in a row must have its own variable**, so you would end up with many strings, as you said. Do note that JPA mandates a database key of some sort.

Fortunately, if you wanted to push your data up, it would be as easy as:

```java
Class.forName("your.database.driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitName");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

PersistenceEntity persistenceEntity; //This is what holds all of your data

em.persist(persistenceEntity); //Push a full row of data
em.getTransaction.commit(); 
con.close();
```

You can also employ [some rather clever ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065708/11198711) to display/get access to this information when not using it directly with the database, to prevent you from calling something like [Java Reflection API](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html).

Answer (score -1):

But why did you named your class Portsmouth ? It's better to make everything more usable. Maybe three classes (3 database tables).

```
Class Tournament{
    private int id;
    Date date;
    String name;
    String place
    Shoot shoot;
}

Class Shoot {
     private int id;
     @OneToMany     
     List<Arrow> arrowList;
}

Class Arrow {
     private int id;
     @ManyToOne
     private Shoot shoot;
     private Integer orderNumber; (1-60)  
     private Integer result (1-10)  instead of Integer can be modified to ENUM ArrowResult from 1-10
}
```

Comment: Portsmouth is the name of the type of shoot. (10 lots of 6 arrows).

Comment: Upps. So in this case I would add to the  Shoot a property String type.